# Refactoring classes with ref to themselves

Tags: c#, refactoring, class-design, inheritance

How can I refactor this code?

```
class Node
{
   public Node Parent { get; set; }
}

class AVLNode
{
   public AVLNode Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use inheritance, but then I have to use type casting:

```
class AVLNode : Node
{
}

class Program
{
   void Main()
   {
      AVLNode a = new AVLNode();
      AVLNode b = a.Parent **as AVLNode**;
   }
}
```

Comment: What refactoring are you trying to perform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try creating a generic interface (INode<out T>). You code will change into something like this:

```
interface INode<out T>
{
  T Parent { get; set; }
}

class Node : INode<Node>
{
  public Node Parent { get; set; }
}

class AVLNode : INode<AVLNode>
{
  public AVLNode Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Your calling code is simply:

```
AVLNode a = new AVLNode();
AVLNode b = a.Parent;
```

Comment: I'd rename the interface to make it more generic, it's an interface to make objects implement a parent value of its own type (so basicly it has nothing to do with Node). PS: You forgot the Property Names in your code sample! :D

Comment: D'oh! I do that all the time for some reason, but usually I have Visual Studio to nag me about it. As for the interface, it's open to being fleshed out later with more things that are inherently node-ish. I can't think of any application for this that isn't a node, because having a parent that has a parent turns into a data structure, which means each child is a node.